# Mail server in the middle responsible for translating from one domain to another

Tags: linux, email, centos6, smtp

The title is a little confusing. We have an internal mail server that can be used to send mail. This internal mail server is only accessible from within our firewall unless we use the mail server's portal.

I have a number of users who prefer to use Gmail due to the interface. While we can use Gmail to fetch mail from our mail server we can not use Gmail to send email due to the firewall (you can't send email such that your Gmail address does not appear in the header).

Basically, I want to set up a SMPT server that I will point gmail to. This server will reside within the firewall and it should be able to relay to our internal mail server. Does anyone know how I could do this? Also what would be some of the security implications I should consider?

Comment: Yes, you can. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370 And your users can even do it themselves.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I mentioned in my post that the SMPT server is not accessible from outside our firewall, thus I can't point google directly there.

Comment: In that case, why don't you just have Gmail talk to your existing SMTP server? It's already set up to send mail anyway.

Comment: The SMTP mail server is only accessible via a portal. Any other type of access to this server is blocked by the firewall. I don't want to allow connection from Google on this mail server as this server is used by various other departments which have their own set up.

Comment: Why not just change the firewall configuration to allow connections from Gmail directly to the real mail server?